# Custom FirebaseUI AuthViewController

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Using the FirebaseUI Auth 1.0 version and swift 3.

Followed the sample and read the explains how to subclass the `FUIAuthPickerViewController` but everything I tried it's giving me a

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`on`let controller = self.authUI!.authViewController()

I exactly copied the example and there is it working, so can someone explain what I did wrong or why this is happening?

Code in my ViewController where I want the user to login

```
ViewController.swift

import Firebase
import FirebaseAuthUI
import FirebaseGoogleAuthUI
import FirebaseFacebookAuthUI

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var remoteConfig: FIRRemoteConfig!
    fileprivate var _refHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle!
    fileprivate var _authHandle: FIRAuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle!


    fileprivate(set) var auth: FIRAuth? = FIRAuth.auth()
    fileprivate(set) var authUI: FUIAuth? = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
    fileprivate(set) var customAuthUIDelegate: FUIAuthDelegate = FUICustomAuthDelegate()


func configAuth() {

        //listen for changes in auth state
        _authHandle = FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth: FIRAuth, currentuser: FIRUser?) in


            self.users.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            if currentuser != nil {
                // User is signed in.

                self.fetchUser()


            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                //self.login()
                self.loginSession()
            }


        })
    }

    func loginSession() {

        self.authUI?.delegate =  self.customAuthUIDelegate
        let googleAuth = FUIGoogleAuth(scopes: [kGoogleUserInfoEmailScope,
                                                kGooglePlusMeScope,
                                                kGoogleUserInfoProfileScope])

        let facebookAuth = FUIFacebookAuth(permissions: ["public_profile",
                                                         "email",
                                                         "user_friends"])
        self.authUI?.providers = [googleAuth, facebookAuth]

        let controller = self.authUI!.authViewController()
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Here the

```
FUICustomAuthDelegate.swift
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuthUI
import FirebaseAuth

class FUICustomAuthDelegate: NSObject, FUIAuthDelegate {

    func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: FIRUser?, error: Error?) {
        guard let authError = error else { return }

        let errorCode = UInt((authError as NSError).code)

        switch errorCode {
        case FUIAuthErrorCode.userCancelledSignIn.rawValue:
            print("User cancelled sign-in");
            break
        default:
            let detailedError = (authError as NSError).userInfo[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] ?? authError
            print("Login error: \((detailedError as! NSError).localizedDescription)");
        }
    }

    func authPickerViewController(forAuthUI authUI: FUIAuth) -> FUIAuthPickerViewController {
        return FUICustomAuthPickerViewController(authUI: authUI)
    }
```

and the

```
FUICustomAuthPickerViewController.swift
import FirebaseAuthUI


@objc(FUICustomAuthPickerViewController)
class FUICustomAuthPickerViewController: FUIAuthPickerViewController {

    @IBAction func onClose(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.cancelAuthorization()
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: See also https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/ios-10-xcode-8-and-swift-3.html

Comment: @Kato there is nothing on that issue written there?